# 01722. 00000 - "invalid number" in SQL Update

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm updating xprojecttype in temp_docmeta table and trying to ignore all the invalid numbers in my below query by including the `"d.xproject_id NOT IN"` clause but it still throws me with `01722. 00000` -  `"invalid number"` error.

```
BEGIN
  FOR X IN
  (SELECT projecttype,pid,enddate FROM temp_project
  )
  LOOP
    UPDATE temp_docmeta d
    SET d.xprojecttype     =X.projecttype
    WHERE d.xproject_id    =X.PID
    AND X.projecttype     IS NOT NULL
    AND X.enddate          > '10-MAR-14 00.00.00'
    AND d.xproject_id NOT IN
      (SELECT TO_NUMBER(xproject_id)
      FROM temp_docmeta
      WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(xproject_id, '[^0-9]+')
      );
  END LOOP;
END ;
```

However when I delete the same set of records with delete statement and then run the above update command it works fine.

```
DELETE
FROM temp_docmeta
WHERE xproject_id IN
  (SELECT xproject_id
  FROM temp_docmeta
  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(xproject_id, '[^0-9]+')
  );
```

I do not want to delete the above records from my temp_docmeta table but need to update the `temp_docmeta` table as in 1st query. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your query tries to change TO_NUMBER all the values you do not want

Maybe you should try

```
 AND d.xproject_id IN
  (SELECT TO_NUMBER(xproject_id)
  FROM temp_docmeta
  WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(xproject_id, '[^0-9]+')
  );
```

but it depends of the order, how TO_NUMBER and REGEXP_LIKE is done

Comment: Can anyone help on this specific issue? OR you can tell me an alternate way to update xprojecttype  column in my table. P.S- when I delete the same set of records with delete statement and then run the above update command it works fine.

Comment: @PulkitBhatia Did you try the above answer? Did it give any error? If there was no error, what was that did not work?

Comment: @EatAPeach Yes i did but it ended giving me same error 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

Answer (score 0):

I changed the datatype of X.PID,as below, `to_char` and it worked, however, when I had changed the datatype of xproject_id to "to number", it did not worked. Strange. Isn't it? 
Or am I missing something?

```
BEGIN
  FOR X IN
  (SELECT projecttype,pid,enddate FROM temp_PROJECT where projecttype IS NOT NULL
  AND enddate      > '10-MAR-14 00.00.00'
  AND PID NOT LIKE '-1'
  )
  LOOP
    UPDATE temp_docmeta
    SET xprojecttype     =X.projecttype
    WHERE xproject_id    =to_char(X.PID)
    AND xproject_id in
      (SELECT UNIQUE(xproject_id)
      FROM temp_docmeta
      WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(xproject_id, '[0-9]+')
      );
  END LOOP;
END;
```